# How to apply the bending effect to objects that are already beveled

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, bevel

I'm going to make a shape that looks like speed bumps. Make sure that the edges of the object are rounded as shown in the following picture:
[image]

However, in order to bend an object using Simple deform, the object must be subdivided, which does not apply to the internal side, as shown in the following picture:
[image]

Is there a good way to bend these objects without loss of volume and corner vertex roundness?

***blender 2.80*, *Used Solidify Modifier.***

[image]

Comment: you could use Curve modifier for example, but you'll have to add some edge loops to make it bend

Comment: @moonboots Thank you very much for your reply. Everything is all right except one. I don't know why a useless face happens to my object. The polygon of the object is broken.

Comment: what do you mean? Perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Once again, thank you for your trouble. I just uploaded the problem file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ok so I screwed my answer because I've imported your object as an .obj into 2.79, so it has applied the modifier, but my answer will help to fix the problem with the face.

You've made a mistake with your object. Actually you have a series of parallel edges made of a series of vertices and that are not filled with faces, and on the bottom you have a big face.

[image]

As I suppose it's not what you want, select this face and delete it (<kbd>X</kbd> (*Delete*) > *Only Faces*). You now have your edges.

[image]

Make sure you have your *LoopTools* addon activated, select all and <kbd>RMB</kbd> (in 2.8) or <kbd>W</kbd> (in 2.7) > *LoopTools* > *Loft*, it will fill the whole thing with faces.

[image]
[image]

Now you have a shape that is already bent, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Also I think you might get rid of some edge loops but again, it depends on your final purpose...